# Spring 4.3.4 with weblogic 12.1 Causing org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;Attribute "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean"

Tags: java, xml, spring

When upgrading to **Spring 4.3.4** I am facing following exception

> nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Attribute
>   "singleton" must be declared for element type "bean"in one of the xmls
>   .

I tried all the ways like

> ```
>  1) Manually gave scope="Singleton"
>  2) Removed the scope since by  default scope is Singleton 
>  3) Gave Singleton="false" 
>  4) Gave scope="prototype" to check..
> ```

This is the DTD I am using

I cleaned the repositories multiple times but no luck.I keep on getting same exception.
I am using weblogic 12.1 and spring-beans.dtd with same version as spring.
Any help would be appreciated.

TIA.

regards
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify your XSDs in your spring configuration xml file? Make sure that you use the right XML schema's for Spring 4.3.

Could you please post the peace of code from configuration file?

Comment: I am using right XSD .Please see this <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">